# Adding and using current geolocation for weather application (widget) using OpenWeatherAPI

Tags: javascript, widget, coffeescript, openweathermap, weather

I am trying to add/use current geolocation on the weather widget that I am trying to make.
Currently, I am able to display information of cities based on an external file. I have very little knowledge about coding.

I'm not in the profession but I am trying to teach myself more about coding.

I have been trying to insert it but I haven't been successful at doing it.
I know there's a lot more code to write, but the ones I've tried had not worked.

I am contemplating if I should write a new one from scratch but it'll take me forever to learn all the necessary data––feels like.

I have read somewhere here and also from OpenWeatherAPI to use
[https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&appid={API](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=%7Blat%7D&lon=%7Blon%7D&appid=%7BAPI) key}
or
const api = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&appid=${apiKey}`

`

```
#mode of widget (light)
mode = "dark"

#api Key from OpenWeatherMap API
apiKey = "API key"

#list of city IDs from API database
cityList = "5814616,1835847"
units = "metric"


command: "curl -s 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=#{cityList}&units=#{units}&appid=#{apiKey}'"
#http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=7046,7049,2008861&units=metric&appid=API Key
refreshFrequency: '15m'



render: (output) -> """
  <div id='weather' class='#{mode}'>#{output}</div>
"""

update: (output) ->
    weatherData = JSON.parse(output)
    console.log(weatherData)

    inner = ""
    inner += "<div class='weatherBox'>" 
    
    for i in [0...weatherData.cnt]
        city = weatherData.list[i].name
        condition = weatherData.list[i].weather[0].main
        temperature = Math.round(weatherData.list[i].main.temp)
        rainChance = weatherData.list[i].clouds.all
        windSpeed = Math.round(weatherData.list[i].wind.speed * 10) / 10
        icon = weatherData.list[i].weather[0].icon

        inner += "<div class='city'><div class='leftBox'><img src='clock-weather.widget/icons/weather/#{icon}.svg' alt='#{icon}'></img></div><div class='middleBox'><div class='cityName'>"
        inner += city
        inner += "</div><div class='condition'>"
        inner += condition
        inner += "</div><div class='rainChance'>Chance of Rain "
        inner += rainChance
        inner += " %</div></div><div class='rightBox'><div class='temperature'>"
        inner += temperature
        inner += "°</div><div class='wind'>"
        inner += windSpeed
        inner += " km/h</div></div></div>"

        console.log(city + condition + temperature)
    
    inner += "</div>"

    $(weather).html(inner)


style: """
    color: white
    font-family: Helvetica Light
    font-weight: 400
    width: 100%
    position: absolute
    top: calc(27%)
    font-size: 14px
    
    #weather
        border-radius: 10px
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.45)
        width: 300px
        height: 70px
        position: absolute
        top: 0
        left 50%
        transform: translate(-50%,0)
        letter-spacing: 0px

    #weather.dark
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)

    #weather.light
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)
        color: black

    #weather.light header
        color: rgba(50,50,50,0.8)

    #weather.dark header
        color: rgba(300,300,300,300.10)

    header 
        padding: 10px 0 10px 0
        display: flex
        flex-direction: row
        position: fixed
        top: 0

    .weatherBox
        overflow-y: scroll
        height: 100%

    .city
        padding: 5px
        display: flex
        flex-direction: row
        //border-top: 1px solid rgba(300,300,300,10)

    .city .leftBox
        width: auto
        padding: 0 15px 0 0
        margin-top: 0 5px 0 0

    .leftBox img
        width: 40px
        height: 40px

    .city .middleBox
        flex-grow: 1
    
    .middleBox .cityName
        font-size: 20px
        line-height: 5px
        font-weight: 500

    .middleBox .condition
        font-size: 13px
        line-height: 20px
        margin-top: 10px

    .middleBox .rainChance
        font-size: 13px
        line-height: 15px

    .city .rightBox
        width: 30%
        text-align: right

    .rightBox .temperature
        font-size: 40px
        line-height: 20px
        font-weight: 300

    .rightBox .wind
        font-size: 13px
        line-height: 45px
    font-weight: 300
        text-align: center
"""
```

`

Comment: What is this widget for? Usually coffeescript is used for old Rails applications, but I know some linux desktop UIs use it for widgets. Which technology is it run on? That will help in finding out where to get geolocation from your system into the widget.

Comment: Hello!
I am wanting to add a desktop widget on a few Mac desktops through the Übersicht app.
One will be hooked up to a TV in a central location.

Here is an image reference on what I did:
https://i.imgur.com/OxjRJue.jpg

Comment: The documentation for uebersicht gives examples of how to use the geolocation api:
https://github.com/felixhageloh/uebersicht#geolocation-api

Comment: @caffeinated.tech thanks! I'll go check it out and see how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be bits of code that are missing here, like whatever is invoking `command` and calling `render()` or `update()`. And I'm a little confused about what your root question or the problem you are facing is.

I don't see anything expressly *wrong* with the sample you shared, but I also don't think that code does anything useful by itself (it's just declaring some variables and functions, but never invoking them). If you're encountering a specific error or issue then the part that is committed here is probably relevant.

That said I do see a few things that might be worth pointing out:

1. The "properties" (variables and functions) you define are declared with a mix of the `foo = "bar"` and `foo: "bar"` styles. That should work in this specific example (especially if all your code is in one file) but I would recommend sticking to one or the other here. The `=` operator is declaring variables with "global" scope, while the `:` operator is declaring attributes of a (in this case implicit and anonymous) JavaScript object. They work a little bit differently and it's probably simpler to use a single style so you don't need to worry about the difference.

   Specifically:

   - If you intend to keep all your code in one file, just using `=` is probably fine. All your variables and functions will (basically) have global scope but that's what you want here. That way you can just use `foo` to reference a variable or `foo(...)` to invoke a function.
   - If you want to "partition" your code into more self-contained units (i.e., scopes or "namespaces"), use the `foo: "bar"` style of assignment, but it probably better to wrap it in an explicit object or class, like this:

     ```coffeescript
     my_app = {
        foo: "bar"

        some_function: ()=>
          console.log "Foo is #{@foo}."
     }
     ```

     etc. In this case you'd use `my_app.foo` and `my_app.some_function()` to reference those properties from outside the object, and `@foo` and `@some_function()` to reference those properties from inside the object. Without the `@` it's a little ambiguous if you were to, say, invoke the `update()` function from within the `render()` function (and may yield an " is not defined" error in some situations).

   Fully explaining the semantics of the object / `:` / `@` stuff is probably out of scope for this answer, so if this is a small, one-off exercise it's probably easiest to just use `=` style definition. In other words, everywhere you have `foo: <something>` change it to `foo = <something>`.
2. It looks like you're probably using a call-out to an external program and secondary process to fetch the data from OpenWeatherMap API data. That is, I assume you must be calling something like `child_process.exec(command)` somewhere in the full program, which in this case will invoke a second program called "curl" to fetch the API response.

   That will work in a lot of contexts, most of the time, but it is not ideal. At best it's slower and more susceptible to run-time errors. At worst, in some environments it won't work at all.

   It would be better to perform the HTTP transaction in node itself, rather than forking out to an external process. You can use the built-in [http module](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v19.x/docs/api/http.html) for this (example [here](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request/)) but popular third-party libraries like [request](https://github.com/request/request) or [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro) may be a little easier to use or at least less verbose.
3. In CoffeeScript the `"""` token (like you are using in the `render` function and `style` variable) declares a multi-line string. Everything between `"""` and the next `"""` will be part of the same string literal, including newline characters and un-escaped double quotes. You could use this to simplify the string concatenation you're doing to `inner` inside the `update` method. E.g., where you have:

   ```coffeescript
   inner += "<div class='city'>..."
   inner += city
   inner += "</div>..."
   ```

   you could write:

   ```coffeescript
   inner += """
     <div class='city'>...
       #{city}
     </div>...
   """
   ```

   instead. It works either way, but the `"""` version may be more readable and easier to write.
4. The CSS code defined in the `style` variable seems to be missing curly-braces (`{` `}`) around the actual rules. E.g. where you have:

   ```css
   #weather.dark
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)
   ```

   normally I would expect:

   ```css
   #weather.dark {
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0)
   }
   ```

   so unless there's some kind of post-processing logic applied to this CSS I think you probably need to wrap each of the indented parts with `{` and `}`.
5. Also it looks like you're using `//` to create single-line comments within the CSS code in the `style` variable. Standard CSS does not use that syntax for comments. You need to use opening `/*` and closing `*/` syntax, even for single lines. (Since you have no space between `//` and the property name it might *look* like the `//` syntax is working here, but that's not a true comment, just an invalid property name.)